# [PHP]Same Array into different Bracket

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP, I have an array which I created and usueally the value of that array are like ['a','b','c'], but I dont know why, my array is in this form : [['a'],['b'],['c']]
Here is my code :

```
<?php 
$res1 = array();
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$dfcv) ;
 while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
 array_push($res1, array(
 $row2['username2'])
 );
 }
echo json_encode($res1);
?>
```

Comment: The additional array is due to the `$row2` being wrapped in an `array()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a php resultset into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515191/convert-a-php-resultset-into-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you add the result into additional an array (`...array(
 $row2['username2'])...`).

```
<?php 
$res1 = array();
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$dfcv) ;
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    array_push($res1, $row2['username2']);

echo json_encode($res1);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php 
    $res1 = array();
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$dfcv) ;
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
        array_push($res1, $row2['username2']);
    }
    echo json_encode($res1);
?>
```

You've put an extra array on `$row2` when you were doing the `array_push()`

```
 array_push($res1, array($row2['username2']));
```