# mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

```
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id AND `type` = 1"), 0) == 1) ? true :false;
```

Comment: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: There is an error in your query ($user_id is probably empty).

Comment: There are literally thousands of questions about this. You have no error checking, and you're passing a faulty query directly to `mysql_result()`. Look at the "Related" section over to the right.

Comment: Instead of nesting `mysql_query()` inside `mysql_result()`, store its resource in a variable and test if is `FALSE`. `echo mysql_error()` to see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id AND `type` = 1");

if (!$result) {
 die(mysql_error());
}

return (mysql_result($result, 0) == 1) ? true :false;
```

at least you will see the error.

Don't assume the query will always run ok, check for errors. Don't put everything in a single line, it makes the code too hard to read. 
Also: be sure to properly escape the input using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) in your case.

Also, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756743/how-to-loop-through-a-mysql-result-set/1756799#1756799)