# I have two Triggers on Mysql Database, but I can list one only with SHOW TRIGGERS

Tags: mysql, list, triggers, show, multiple-instances

I created two triggers for MySQL database. But I want to get the trigger names and statements, but when I try I get back one array of one trigger only with code:

```
$TriggersOfArray = (mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SHOW TRIGGERS")));
```

I tried with \G parameter, but does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over a result set to get all the results. mysql_fetch_assoc() gives you the associative array for the current row only. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756743/how-to-loop-through-a-mysql-result-set).

Comment: Thank you. Its true. I did it with another situation but I "forgot" with this query :)