# How to create loop query in php?

Tags: php, loops

Now this is the scenario I have voting system in php, so I want to display the candidates based on the organization so after that if the voters log in to the system based on there organization. Just comparison of org_id.

This is my sample mysql query.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE position='President' and org_name='IntOrg'");
```

Now the question is how to loop a query to select and depends on the org_id of candidates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to loop through a mysql result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756743/how-to-loop-through-a-mysql-result-set)

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you usually do SQL. You would simply get all the candidates, `order` them by `org_name` and then iterate through the result.

But maybe I'm misunderstanding you and your question is actually "how to do a loop in PHP", in which case I'd say "read a PHP tutorial".

Answer (score 0):

**Example (MySQLi Object-oriented)** *[source](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)*

And if you want to prevent '*hacking*' in the DB, you should read about [**Mysql Injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2529486) and use **PDO** or **Mysqli** insted of *Mysql, which is depreciated.*

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE position='President' and org_name='IntOrg'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
/* Check if you have result */
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    /* This is a loop */
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo  $row["column name"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```