# How to use total rows in mysql table for loop's counter in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I want to use my total rows in mysql tabel for loop's counter, so I need to count the rows in my table right?

This is my obviously wrong code:

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pemain_winger");
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    for($a=1;$a<=$rows;$a++) {
        echo ...
       }
```

Its always give Undefined offset: 3 error, pls help me :(

Comment: from where you got `$nama` variable? As well use `while` loop to iterate

Comment: Whoops my bad... So I should use while instead for?

Comment: yes................

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756743/how-to-loop-through-a-mysql-result-set