# Condition with SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement

I've come to see you for a question. Is there a condition in SQL that allows you to do that:

```sql
IF(sup = void) {
}
```

Database

```
id | name | lastname   |     city  | mail          |  number  |     picture   | ... 
 1 | kiwi |    kiwi    |   USA    | kiwi@gmail.com | 0000000000 | default.img | (vide)
```

Comment: Please add the database technology you are using.
There is an IF clause and also a CASE clause, depending on what you want to achieve.
Also i assume void is NULL. in that case you can use IS NULL

Comment: I assume what you want could be achieved by "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE sup IS NULL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE sup IS NULL
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

Update after reading your comment.

```
$test = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ressource_view WHERE ID = 1")
```

Will give you the result of your query. Be careful as there could be multiple rows returned.

To fetch the first row

```
$row = $result->fetch_array()
```

And then to check if the sup column of your row is null you can use:

```
if(is_null($row['sup']))
{
}
```

Or this will have the same effect

```
if($row['sup'] === NULL)
{
}
```

But best to tag your question with PHP, MySQL. Your problem seems to be more on the PHP side and someone else could provide a better answer.

Comment: So I have to do: $test = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ressource_view WHERE ID = '1' AND sup IS NULL");<br/>if($test) { <br/>echo 'The box is empty';<br/>}<br/><br/>Sorry I'm a rookie.

Comment: That looks like PHP code so I assume you are using MySQL as the DBMS. Please tag the question with those keywords as well.
Also ID is genrally numeric so you would need to do ID=1 instead of ID='1'.

But you need to explain what you are trying to achieve, so I can help you.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3MTZ.png -> Database image

Actually, that's what I'd like to do. If for example id='5' and empty then I display this. It's to make a dynamic flowchart.
Sorry I had a little trouble using stackoverflow.

Comment: I think what you want is parse through the results and whenever sup is null display something additional. You could read how to do that here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756743/how-to-loop-through-a-mysql-result-set